# TripleDES encrypt and decrypt in javascript - CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, react-native, encryption, cryptojs

I'm using CryptoJS library to `TripleDES` function but the decrypt data doesn't work. my decrypted data dons't return the origin string.

```
var t = "a";
var d = "john";
var key = CryptoJS.MD5(t).toString()
var param = CryptoJS.TripleDES.encrypt(d, key).toString();
console.log('decrypt',CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(param, key).toString())
console.log('encrypt',param) // it should return `john`. but it returns a different value.
```

the result of this encryption:

```
decrypt 6a6f686e
encrypt U2FsdGVkX19Ww0uMTSo+qAV5PVzsEhSR
```

https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: You must the answer ...

Answer (score 5):

solved:

You should `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8` inside `toString` function.

```
console.log('decrypt',CryptoJS.TripleDES.decrypt(param, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
```